# how to read file sent from http post in jersy

Tags: web-services, rest

this code i tested for values

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getE(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    String out = "";
    Map<String, String> l = fileMetaData.getParameters();
    Collection<String> s = l.values();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        out += i.next()+"      ";
    }
```

return out;
}

i am getting this exception

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String my.Service.getE(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[text/plain], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class my.Service, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@4023c98]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String my.Service.getE(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']

Dependencies are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

my service class

```
@Path("empdata")
```

public class Service {

```
EmpService service = new EmpService();
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getE(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    String out = "";
    Map<String, String> l = fileMetaData.getParameters();
    Collection<String> s = l.values();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        out += i.next()+"      ";
    }
    return out;//
}
```

}

and i registered my ResourceConfig sub class

[this is how i am sending request and file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qfCg.png)
[this is how my request header and body part looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFTzp.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Please show a bit of code.

Comment: and i am using REST console of chrome extension

Comment: What framework do you use for your REST API?

Comment: Show the dependencies you have in your project.

Comment: Ensure your `jersey` artifacts are in the same version. You are mixing multiple versions.

Comment: Have you registered the `MultipartFeature` as described in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38913315/1426227)? Looks like you missed that.

Comment: *still getting same exception* means nothing to me. Describe your problem properly. What did you do?

Comment: no i haven't registered. How to register and can u send me a sample code for returning file data by this process

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception for fileMetaData.getParameters()

Comment: What your request looks like? How are you sending the file? Make some effort to debug your application.

Comment: i updated my question with a picture of the request console please take a look

Comment: What param name are you using the send the file? The `@FormDataParam` value needs to match it.

Comment: its fileUpload1 but i am not getting the contents of file

Comment: i am getting file name but i am unable to get the file data into the program

Comment: So use `@FormDataParam("fileUpload1")`. The content of the file is available in the `InputStream`.

Comment: yes thanks i got the answer its my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding Jersey multipart dependecy

To use multipart features in your Jersey application, you need to add the [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html) module to your `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using Maven make sure to have all needed dependencies (see the [`jersey-media-multipart`](https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.23.2/jersey/project/jersey-media-multipart/dependencies.html) artifact dependencies) on the classpath.

### Registering the multipart feature

Besides adding the dependency, you need to register the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html). See the approaches below:

If you have an [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class, do as following:

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MultipartFeature.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        register(MultipartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

If you don't have an [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) sub-class, you can register the [`MultiPartFeature`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/MultiPartFeature.html) in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor. The specific resource, provider and feature fully-qualified class names can be provided in a *comma-separated value* of [`jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_CLASSNAMES) initialization parameter.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

### Handling multipart requests

Use the [`@FormDataParam`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataParam.html) annotation to bind the named body part(s) of a `multipart/form-data` request entity body to a resource method parameter, as following:

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
                       @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData) {
    ...
}
```

---

For more details, check the [Jersey documentation about multipart requests](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart).

Comment: i have edited my question please give me solution thanks!

Comment: sorry since iam using this site for first time i am unaware of it