# Creation API of an external service. Sending binary data

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jax-rs

The external service is not mine, it's "Freshdesk".

I managed to create a Java-API with Java-ws-rs to be able to call its WS to create a "Ticket".

Here is my Interface:

```
@Path("/api/v2/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface FreshdeskService {

  @POST
  @Path("tickets")
  TicketResponse create(TicketRequest ticketRequests);

}
```

And here my object (I removed a lot of field cause it's not necessary here):

```
public class TicketRequest {
  private String name;
  private Long requester_id;
  private String email;
}
```

Everything is fine and the ticket can be created. My issue is when I tried to add an attachment to this ticket. Here is the documentation: http://developers.freshdesk.com/api/#create_ticket

The curl command is:

```
curl -v -u user@yourcompany.com:test -F "attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment1.ext" -F "attachments[]=@/path/to/attachment2.ext" -F "email=example@example.com" -F "subject=Ticket Title" -F "description=this is a sample ticket" -X POST 'https://domain.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets'
```

As you can see, they turn the data into a form with `-F`. But I don't know how to manage to do that with my API. I can add an `List<File>` in my `TicketRequest` object but it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Can you slightly elaborate the last part of your question? I am getting curl and other stuff.

Comment: Could you please post the complete client code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Freshdesk documentation states the following regarding creating a ticket with attachments:

> This API request must have its content-type set to `multipart/form-data`.

Hence, you won't be able to create a ticket with attachments using JSON.

---

Depending on the JAX-RS implementation you are using, there are different ways to send/receive files.

If you are using Jersey 2.x, you need to add the multipart dependency and register the multipart feature in order to handle multipart requests. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38913315) for more details on how to do that. You can use [`FormDataMultiPart`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataMultiPart.html) to upload the file from your client.